# Timer Class ... not updating

Tags: c#

Hi I made this code that will show when it run a clock and then ask the user to enter new seconds and minutes and hours so they will be added to the old clock I did so but the results are wrong where is the mistake

the main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer S1 = new Timer();
        S1.Sec = 10;
        S1.Min = 25;
        S1.Hour = 23;
        S1.Read();
        S1.Write();
    }
```

the timer class

```
namespace Uni_19
{
class Timer
{
    private int Seconds;
    private int Minutes;
    private int Hours;
    private int Days = 0;

    public int Sec
    {
        get { return Seconds; }
        set
        {
            Seconds = value % 60;
            Minutes += value / 60;
        }
    }
    public int Min
    {
        get { return Minutes; }
        set
        {
            Minutes = value % 60;
            Hour += (value / 60);
        }
    }
    public int Hour
    {
        get { return Hours; }
        set 
        {
            Hours = value % 24;
            Days += value / 24;
        }
    }
    public int Day
    {
        get { return Days; }
        set { Days = Hour / 24; }
    }
    public int AddSec(int A)
    {
        Sec += A;
        return Sec;
    }
    public int AddMin(int B)
    {
        Min += B;
        return Min;
    }
    public int AddHour(int C)
    {
        Hour = Hour + (C % 24);
        return Hour;
    }
    public int AddDay(int D)
    {
        Day += D;
        return Day;
    }
    public void Read()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time Is: {0}", Hours + " : " + Minutes + " : " + Seconds);
        Console.Write("Time Added (in Seconds): ");
        Sec = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Time Added (in Minutes): ");
        Min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Time Added (in Houres): ");
        Hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Time Is: {0}", AddDay(Day) + " : " + AddHour(Hour) + " : " + AddMin(Min) + " : " + AddSec(Sec));
    }
}
}
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the user input for both *setting* the day and *adding* to it. The old time is completely overwritten and not used in the calculation.

```
Sec = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  // Calls the setter 'Sec' which overwrites Seconds.
```

On top of that, the AddSec routine can return a number greater than 60, which is probably not what you want.

What is the specification for your homework assignment? Your Timer class is completely unnecessary in .NET because the functionality it provides is already covered by the DateTime and TimeSpan classes. I'm assuming though that you are not allowed to do that otherwise it would make your assignment too easy?

Possible fix, changing `Sec =` to `AddSec`, etc:

```
Console.Write("Time Added (in Seconds): ");
AddSec(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
Console.Write("Time Added (in Minutes): ");
AddMin(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
Console.Write("Time Added (in Houres): ");
AddHour(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

...

Console.WriteLine("New Time Is: {0}", Day + " : " + Hour + " : " + Min + " : " + Sec);
```

Full source code:

```
using System;

namespace Uni_19
{
    class Timer
    {
        private int Seconds;
        private int Minutes;
        private int Hours;
        private int Days = 0;

        public int Sec
        {
            get { return Seconds; }
            set
            {
                Seconds = value % 60;
                Minutes += value / 60;
            }
        }
        public int Min
        {
            get { return Minutes; }
            set
            {
                Minutes = value % 60;
                Hour += (value / 60);
            }
        }
        public int Hour
        {
            get { return Hours; }
            set
            {
                Hours = value % 24;
                Days += value / 24;
            }
        }
        public int Day
        {
            get { return Days; }
            set { Days = Hour / 24; }
        }
        public int AddSec(int A)
        {
            Sec += A;
            return Sec;
        }
        public int AddMin(int B)
        {
            Min += B;
            return Min;
        }
        public int AddHour(int C)
        {
            Hour = Hour + (C % 24);
            return Hour;
        }
        public int AddDay(int D)
        {
            Day += D;
            return Day;
        }
        public void Read()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Time Is: {0}", Hours + " : " + Minutes + " : " + Seconds);
            Console.Write("Time Added (in Seconds): ");
            AddSec(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.Write("Time Added (in Minutes): ");
            AddMin(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.Write("Time Added (in Houres): ");
            AddHour(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        public void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Time Is: {0}", Day + " : " + Hour + " : " + Min + " : " + Sec);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer S1 = new Timer();
            S1.Sec = 10;
            S1.Min = 25;
            S1.Hour = 23;
            S1.Read();
            S1.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :-( Im lost lots of thing to do
So how can I fixed it ?!

Comment: Updated with suggestion for bug fix.

Comment: now only the seconds work fine but still i got wrong answers on min and hours and days the values I added was 3 for sec and 3 for min and 0 for hours and the results was New Time Is: 1 : 68 : 3 : 13

Comment: Using your code, and making only the changes I described above, I get '1 : 2 : 25 : 13'.

Comment: So what should I cahnge in the methods ... I can't find somthin to correct

Comment: I've posted the full source code for the changes I made. You should be able to just copy and paste it into your editor and see that it gives the results that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure instead of reinventing it

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer but more of a suggestion:

For your Write() method, try using either ToString or changing your code to something easier on the eye:

```
Console.WriteLine("New Time Is: {0} : {1} : {2} : {3}",AddDay(Day),AddHour(Hour),AddMin(Min),AddSec(Sec));
```

Might make it a bit easier for you to change in the future.

How come you have decided to use your own Timer class, is it not suitable to use the provided DateTime class?

Answer (score 0):

This method seems suspect to me, what is it meant to be doing?

```
public void Write()
{
    Console.WriteLine("New Time Is: {0}", AddDay(Day) + " : " + AddHour(Hour) + " : " + AddMin(Min) + " : " + AddSec(Sec));
}
```

Also please use some convention when encapsulating fields,

```
private int _seconds
public int Seconds {get;set;}
```